# spring smtp server is rejecting the authentication request

Tags: spring, email, smtp

This is the application.properties file.

The username and password are 100% correct. I put fake values for security reasons of this post

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=MTMS@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=Password1****
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Here is the full logs when failed

```
DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 1.0.0
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/home/brendan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/jakarta.mail/1.0.0/jakarta.mail-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/home/brendan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/jakarta.mail/1.0.0/jakarta.mail-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], smtps=jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], imaps=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], pop3s=jakarta.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: URL jar:file:/home/brendan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/jakarta.mail/1.0.0/jakarta.mail-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: jar:file:/home/brendan/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/jakarta.mail/1.0.0/jakarta.mail-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a11-20020a05600c224b00b003ee1b2ab9a0sm8259203wmm.11 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
EHLO brendan-Latitude-E7470
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [88.174.90.243]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO brendan-Latitude-E7470
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [88.174.90.243]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=MTMS@gmail.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
2023-04-08T18:49:50.943+02:00 ERROR 5247 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed] with root cause

jakarta.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials a11-20020a05600c224b00b003ee1b2ab9a0sm8259203wmm.11 - gsmtp
```

I checked the settings of the accont i am using and two-factor authentication is disabled for the account to authenticate with the SMTP server.

The email account I am using is not locked out or suspended.